# Apply Householder reflector on a 3 by 3 matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

I know how to apply that on a 3 by 2 matrix. However, when it comes to a 3 by 3 matrix, I am kind of lost.

For example A is 
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        4 & 8 & 1 \\
        0 & 2 & -2 \\
        3 & 6 & 7 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
And I know v, w and x. I used the formula to find H_1, which is $$
        \begin{matrix}
        4/5 & 0 & 3/5 \\
        0 & 4/5 & 0 \\
        3/5 & 0 & -4/5 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
And $H_1A$ is $$
        \begin{matrix}
        5 & 10 & 5 \\
        0 & 8/5 & -8/5 \\
        0 & 0 & -5 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
Despite the first column, there are still two columns left. How am I supposed to find the new x and w and how to proceed from here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you forget about the first row and column and compute the reflector for the remaining $2×2$ matrix. This gets extended to a $3×3$ matrix as block-diagonal matrix with the unit matrix in the upper diagonal block.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate it?

Comment: This answer says the same as the more detailed answer to your other question on the topic. In your specific problem, you are done as $H_1A$ already is in upper triangular form. If you need to find a second reflector, it would be the one that flips the sign on the second entry in each column. Please post a source or the formulas for $v$, $w$ and $x$ as these variable names by themselves to not explain much.